# Olá, meu problema é que o email está sendo enviado só que quando vou checar no email ao inves de mostrar o email do remetente mostra o do destinatario

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
protected void btnEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string desEmail = "exemplo@gmail.com";
        string remetenteEmail = txtEmail.Text; //O e-mail do remetente

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        mail.To.Add(desEmail);

        mail.From = new MailAddress(remetenteEmail, txtNome.Text, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

        mail.Subject = txtAssunto.Text;

        mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        mail.Body = txtMensagem.Text;

        mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        mail.Priority = MailPriority.High; //Prioridade do E-Mail



        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();  //Adicionando as credenciais do seu e-mail e senha:

        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(desEmail, "123456");



        client.Port = 587; // Esta porta é a utilizada pelo Gmail para envio

        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //Definindo o provedor que irá disparar o e-mail

        client.EnableSsl = true; //Gmail trabalha com Server Secured Layer

        try

        {

            client.Send(mail);

           lblMensagem.Text = "Envio do E-mail com sucesso";

            lblMensagem.Visible = true;

        }

        catch (Exception ex)

        {

            lblMensagem.Text = "Ocorreu um erro ao enviar:" + ex.Message;

            lblMensagem.Visible = true;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu acho que você esta apenas se confundindo em questão de Remetente (Quem esta enviado o e-mail) e Destinatário(Quem vai receber o e-mail) no seu código, Tanto que no SMTP vc usa o Destinatário.. Porém o SMTP tem que ser do Remetente (Quem envia o e-mail, no caso seria o seu servidor de e-mail) e o Destinatário é quem vai receber, Este é variavel que é o informado no campo txtEmail.Text;

Comment: Seu erro ai é basicamente nesta linha: client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(desEmail, "123456");
Ao invés de desEmail vc tem que por remetenteEmail e inverter a constante la em cima

Answer (score 0):

Como fiz o comentário acima, você esta se confundindo em relação a Remetente (Quem esta enviando o e-mail) e Destinatário (Quem receberá o e-mail), no caso o e-mail que é informado no campo txtEmail, eu ajustei seu código e fiz os comentários para você entender melhor:

```
protected void btnEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //E-mail do destinatário (Quem Receberá o e-mail
        string desEmail = txtEmail.Text; //Recebe o valor informado no campo no Form

        //Remetente é quem envia o e-mail (Deve ser o mesmo do seu servidor de SMTP) no caso gmail
        string remetenteEmail = "exemplo@gmail.com";//O e-mail do remetente


        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        //Adiciona o destinatário
        mail.To.Add(desEmail);

        //Adiciona o remetente
        mail.From = new MailAddress(remetenteEmail, txtNome.Text, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

        //Assunto
        mail.Subject = txtAssunto.Text;

        mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        mail.Body = txtMensagem.Text;

        mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        mail.Priority = MailPriority.High; //Prioridade do E-Mail


        //SMTP é o servidor de e-mail que irá enviar o e-mail
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

        //Aqui a credencial tem que ser de quem esta enviando, no caso o Remetente
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(remetenteEmail, "123456");

        client.Port = 587; // Esta porta é a utilizada pelo Gmail para envio

        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //Definindo o provedor que irá disparar o e-mail

        client.EnableSsl = true; //Gmail trabalha com Server Secured Layer

        try

        {

            client.Send(mail);

            lblMensagem.Text = "Envio do E-mail com sucesso";

            lblMensagem.Visible = true;

        }

        catch (Exception ex)

        {

            lblMensagem.Text = "Ocorreu um erro ao enviar:" + ex.Message;

            lblMensagem.Visible = true;

        }
    }
```